# ReCAPTCHA responses all fail

Tags: php, recaptcha, captcha

I have had reCAPTCHA V2 on my contact form for 1 year without a problem. Now since 5-7 days it has stopped working and i don't now why, all responses fail all of a sudden. I have done 0 changes on the site or any of the files for several months. If you tick the checkmark in the ReCaptacha box you will get the error "Validation Required!" which is the response given if the validation should fail as you can see in the code bellow.

Anyone got any idea why it would stop working just out of the blue when 0 changes has been done? I have had 10 different people try to use the contact form but everyone get's "Validation Required!" as an error.

Can recaptacha get blocked by the server firewall or something?

```
    //reCAPTCHA validation
    if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {

            require('component/recaptcha/src/autoload.php');

            $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha(SECRET_KEY, new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\SocketPost());

            $resp = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

              if (!$resp->isSuccess()) {
                            $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => '<b>Captcha</b> Validation Required!'));
                            die($output);
              }
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Does `$resp` contain any information?

Comment: Any recommendations  on how could i check / do this ? i have no idea what i can do to debug it.